# Diagnostic with ID is not supported by the analyzer, but it's in the SupportedDiagnostics property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, .net-standard

I have a C# code analyzer base class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using CodeQuality.Shared;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

namespace CodeQuality
{
    internal abstract class CodeAnalyzerBase<TSyntaxNode> : DiagnosticAnalyzer
        where TSyntaxNode : SyntaxNode
    {
        private readonly object contextLock = new object();
        private SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context;

        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(this.Rule, DiagnosticDescriptors.AnalyzerExceptionRule);

        /// <summary>The syntax kind to which you want to register the AnalyzeNode method</summary>
        /// <value>The kind of the syntax.</value>
        internal abstract SyntaxKind SyntaxKind { get; }

        protected abstract DiagnosticDescriptor Rule { get; }

        protected SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this.contextLock)
                {
                    return this.context;
                }
            }

            set
            {
                lock (this.contextLock)
                {
                    this.context = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // we want concurrent execution, but it's annoying while actively debugging
                context.EnableConcurrentExecution(); 
            }

            context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.Analyze | GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);

            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(this.AnalyzeNode, this.SyntaxKind);
        }

        internal void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Context = context;

                if (this.Context.Node.SyntaxTree == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (!(this.Context.Node is TSyntaxNode node))
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.AnalyzeNode(node);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var location = this.Context.Node.GetLocation();
                var lineSpan = location.GetLineSpan();

                DebugHelper.LogException(
                    e,
                    lineSpan.Path,
                    lineSpan.StartLinePosition.Line,
                    $"Supported Rules: {string.Join(Environment.NewLine, this.SupportedDiagnostics.Select(r => r.Id))}");

                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(
                        DiagnosticDescriptors.AnalyzerExceptionRule,
                        location,
                        $"File: {lineSpan.Path}",
                        $"Line: {lineSpan.StartLinePosition.Line}",
                        $"Exception message: {e.Message}",
                        $"Inner Exception: {e.InnerException}",
                        $"Stack Trace: {e.StackTrace}");

                this.Context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }

        internal abstract void AnalyzeNode(TSyntaxNode node);
    }
}
```

I have several implementations of this base class. Originally, I didn't have the try catch in the parent AnalyzeNode method, so when the analyzer threw an exception, it would fail the compilation of the project being analyzed. These analyzers aren't *absolutely crucial* to our build process, so I didn't want an analyzer error to stop the overall build process from continuing. With this in mind, I added the try/catch which is meant to create a compiler warning which contains data such as file in which the error was thrown, line, message, etc. If I see the warning, I know I need to look at that location/use case and handle it in the analyzer.

When I install the DLL into the projects of my solution, the concrete implementations do catch the things they are supposed to catch. However, sometimes the following error is reported:

AD0001  Analyzer '{concrete implemenation here}' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' with message 'Reported diagnostic with ID '{DiagnosticDescriptors.AnalyzerExceptionRule.Id}' is not supported by the analyzer.

I've tried debugging, but I never seem to hit the catch block while debugging. Additionally, I added a line to log the SupportedDiagnostics right before I try to report the warning diagnostic, and the Supported diagnostics are what I expect (the rule defined in each concrete type and the DiagnosticDescriptors.AnalyzerExceptionRule). However, it still throws an error when attempting to report.

Here's a simple example of a concrete implementation:

```
// analyzes to ensure there are no empty catch blocks unless they contain comments
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    internal class EmptyCatchBlockAnalyzer : CodeAnalyzerBase<CatchClauseSyntax>
    {
        internal override SyntaxKind SyntaxKind => SyntaxKind.CatchClause;

        protected override DiagnosticDescriptor Rule => DiagnosticDescriptors.EmptyCatchBlockRule;

        internal override void AnalyzeNode(CatchClauseSyntax node)
        {
            if (node.Block == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (node.Block.Statements == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!node.Block.Statements.Any() && !node.Block.DescendantTrivia().Any(trivia => trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia) || trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia)))
            {
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(this.Rule, node.CatchKeyword.GetLocation());
                this.Context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've done a lot of logging in various areas of these files to try and get a sense for when things happen. The analyzers are all constructed and Initialized properly (I think), as logging the SupportedDiagnostics at those times have shown the correct codes as well.

Based on the code in the base class, I sort of expected any error in the `AnalyzeNoe` execution in my concrete classes would result in a Warning diagnostic. Here's the diagnostic used in the catch block:

```
internal static DiagnosticDescriptor AnalyzerExceptionRule => new DiagnosticDescriptor(
          "ID0000",
          "Code analyzer exception",
          $"An error occurred while attempting to run code analysis.",
          DiagnosticCategories.Usage, // "Usage"
          DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
          isEnabledByDefault: true);
```

Here's a diagnostic to match the sample concrete implementation above:

```
internal static DiagnosticDescriptor EmptyCatchBlockRule => new DiagnosticDescriptor(
           "ID0050",
           "Empty Catch Block",
           "Code contains an empty catch block. Add code to handle the error or add a comment justifying the existence of this empty catch block.",
           DiagnosticCategories.Syntax, // "Syntax"
           DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
           isEnabledByDefault: true);
```

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers are you using? It is recommended that you use the latest version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers. If this doesn't work please provide a more complete error message.

Comment: I've updated the analyzer project's references and it seems that the error is happening less frequently, but it's still happening. One of the problems I have here is that the error that is reported in the project being analyzed doesn't have information in it like the line or the file which caused the error. I'm really not getting much more than that message that I shared in the post. I'm just not sure what I need to do to debug it further.

Comment: Since you were kind enough to answer originally, @wenbingeng-MSFT, I wanted to close the loop on this. Any time the issue occurred in a project after the version updates, I had to delete my .vs folder for the solution in question. Then it worked. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Glad to be able to help you, I edited and posted the answer. You can mark it so that you can help more people.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you use the latest version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers. And delete the .vs folder after update.